# Find the coordinates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a scenario where I need to find the starting and ending coordinates between the gap. The table structure would be

[image]

From the above table the output will be

[image]

Whenever there is a gap I need to take the above value as end point  and current value as starting point. Could you please help here with SQL query. I tried with LAG but still not got the required output.

Comment: What is the type of your `TIME` column and why do you only store the time?

Comment: Please post the query you have tried.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It stores the complete datetime.. I just posted time here as the input will be only one date

Answer (score 0):

created a temp table:

```
create table tmp_time_gap
(time  date,
 llat  varchar2(10 char),
 llong varchar2(10 char));
```

and loaded the sample data:

```
insert into tmp_time_gap values (trunc(sysdate) + INTERVAL '11:00:00' hour to second(0), '50.23', '4.3');
insert into tmp_time_gap values (trunc(sysdate) + INTERVAL '11:00:20' hour to second(0), '51.23', '5.3');
...
```

Using lag/lead and a case expression:

```
select time, llat, llong, start_stop
from
(
    select t.*,
           case when t.time_diff_seconds2 is null then 'Start'  --first row
                when t.time_diff_seconds is null  then 'End'  --last row
                when t.time_diff_seconds > 20 then 'End'
                when t.time_diff_seconds2 > 20 then 'Start'
                else null
           end start_stop
    from (
          select time, 
                 (lead(time, 1) over (order by time)-time) * 24*60*60 as time_diff_seconds,
                 (time - lag(time, 1) over (order by time)) * 24*60*60 as time_diff_seconds2,
                 llat, llong
          from tmp_time_gap
          ) t
)          
where start_stop is not null
```

Result:

[image: Query result]

Notes: if you have a "gap" right after the first row, then the first two rows will be a 'Start' row. I don't know if this could happen in your dataset, but if it is an issue, you could tweak the case statement, and have 'Start-End' label for this scenario. The same could happen for the last row (two End labels), and actually, this could happen inbetween too, e.g.:

```
insert into tmp_time_gap values (trunc(sysdate) + INTERVAL '11:07:00' hour to second(0), '60.00', '14.00');
```

The latter could be solved by adding the following condition after the '--last row' branch of the case stmt:

```
when t.time_diff_seconds > 20 and t.time_diff_seconds2 > 20 then 'Start-End (middle)'
```